# R with a special topology is locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

Is $(\mathbb{R},T)$ with T being generated by the basis $\{(a,b] :a,b ∈ \mathbb{R},a < b\} $ locally compact?

Is there anybody who can tell me the difference between the topology above and the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$? Thanks.

Comment: Reference topic: Sorgenfrey Line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ is sometimes called the *upper limit topology*. It differs significantly from the usual topology. For instance, the set $(0,1]$ is by definition open in the upper limit topology, but it is not open in the usual topology: there is no $\epsilon>0$ such that $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\subseteq(0,1]$.

Here’s a HINT regarding local compactness: Is $(0,1]$ is compact in the upper limit topology? Consider the open cover $\left\{\left(\frac1n,1\right]:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$. Once you’ve answered this, you should be able to decide whether $1$ (or any other point) has any compact nbhd.